# Add link to search tips

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, hyperlinks

*(There must be something obvious I've missed, if so apologies in advance...)*

I was looking for the [page with the search tips](https://stackoverflow.com/search), and couldn't find it. Its not on the main page, not in the FAQ, not in the first page of the extended FAQ. To find it, I had to search for something like [asdasdasdasdasd](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asdasdasdasdasd), which asked me if I'd like to "See our search links". Well yes, I would, but I'd like an easier way to do it.

Suggestions:

- Clicking on the magnifying glass could go there.
- There could be a question mark to the right of the search box, like so: ([?](https://stackoverflow.com/search))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears on every search result page (screenshot presented in ye olde traditional hand-drawn Meta style)

http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/5870/sosearchtips.png

- doing a blank search will take you to the search help page
- doing a search that returns no results will provide search tips as well (though different ones, I need to make sure they're cross-linked..)

Comment: **↑** For breaking out the Paint skillz.

Comment: Is that Mister Fantastic or Plastic Man helping with the search?

Comment: It may not be obvious (at least for me) that to get to the advanced search you have to perform a blank or dummy search first. Why not add a direct link somewhere?

Comment: @pesche there is a direct link in the [faq](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq), of course, nobody reads that

Comment: Yeah, should have gone there again. It's probably why I knew that there is a Ninja page and then I started searching meta instead of the FAQ...

Answer (score 3):

I would be fine with a ? beside the box, but clicking on the magnifying glass is canonically accepted to mean "Search".

Answer (score 1):

Searching for something that returns very few results will provide a link to the search tips page in the sidebar. Also, searching for nothing will bring you to this page (Just hit enter in the search box).

Comment: Useful to know in the future (searching for nothing). I'm not sure if we could be expected to know that though.