# Search link near the search box

Tags: feature-request, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Advanced search help should be available by the search box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114358/advanced-search-help-should-be-available-by-the-search-box)

I know we recently added the Search link to the FAQ based off this suggestion: [Add link to search tips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17080/add-link-to-search-tips)

And while that's excellent...I've been a member for 7 months, and just found that we have the [search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search).

Would it be too hard to add a "More Options" link to the search box, like either to the right of it, or just below it? Or heck, maybe some jQuery magic or something, and when you click in it, spawn a link below it that says "More Options". I would have been using it a long time ago, I just simply didn't know it was there.

I also found out today it's in the side bar, after you do a normal search, but wasn't really looking there either; as I only used the normal search 2 or 3 times, before I mapped the search to Google and my search bar.